# Flagging worldbuilding questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When flagging a question, selecting **should be closed...** -> **off-topip because...**-> **this question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network** gives only two choices : meta.writers and English SE.

[image: Migration choices]

Since migrations to Worldbuilding SE are relatively common, shouldn't it be an option when flagging?

It could maybe make moderation slightly easier and/or faster.

Comment: Quick tally: we've migrated 11 questions to Worldbuilding and 87 to EL&U.  (The per-site meta is always an option so I didn't look at those.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Ah, I thought it was more frequent. I guess it would not be particularly useful then.

Comment: I thought it was too, but I decided to go look.  If the rate picks up please raise it again!  Beta sites get custom migration paths only by special dispensation, and I predict that this request would be declined today.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: What timeframe do those numbers cover? Worldbuilding.SE is waaay more recent than EL&U.

Comment: @Standback yeah, that's lifetime of this site, so this ratio should change over time.  OTOH, 11 migrations since Worldbuilding came into existence isn't a lot *now*, so I'm pretty sure (from past experience on another site where I too proposed a migration target) that the CM response will be "wait until you have more of a track record".  All that said, I'm posting this in comments because it's meant as information but not a definitive answer -- just providing context for people who want to move forward.

Comment: Oh please, can I vote for this too? I feel like there have been a *ton* of these. I mean, I get why those questions are asked here, but Worldbuilding is really the place for those.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum Maybe there was only 11 migrations to worlbuilding because some users (me included) deleted their WB questions here and re-asked them in WB before the admins had the chance to migrate them. I too feel like there have been more than 11 of these.

Comment: I will second the feeling that there are more than eleven. I seem to recall finding at least three myself within the last month alone. But I'll leave this matter in your more than capable hands.

Comment: You will always have more migrations to cites that you offer as options for migration. I have lost count of the number of times I wanted to suggest migration to Worldbuilders, English Language Learners, History, and probably others. Without those options, you have to flag it as something else. It's not like the current list is too long to scan. Why not add at least the top half dozen likely candidates?

Comment: Could we take a look again at the statistics for migrations to Worldbuilding and see if they warrant adding the option? I still feel like this would be a good addition.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I thought the comment would send this question to the top, but apparently I was mistaken. Hence the mention. :)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a tally of the migrations we've made since September 2014, when the Worldbuilding site entered public beta.  (Some settling might have occurred during shipping -- i.e. I hand-counted these because we don't have tools to supply all-time numbers.)

- EL&U (built-in option): 79
- Worldbuilding: 15
- English Language Learners: 9
- Law: 7
- Ebooks: 6
- Super User: 6
- Literature: 4
- Academia: 4
- Science Fiction & Fantasy: 3
- TeX: 3
- Meta (built-in option): 2
- Workplace: 2
- History: 2

And one each for: Physics, Aviation, Graphic Design, Freelancing, Health, WebApps, Biology, Stack Overflow, RPG, Open Source, Ask Different, Community Building.

In the last 90 days, we've migrated one question to Worldbuilding and the migration was rejected.  (I don't have older rejection stats.)

Worldbuilding is our most popular non-EL&U migration target, and probably more migrations would be suggested if it were a built-in option like EL&U is.  It seems reasonable to ask if we can add it.

**Update:** Tim Post said [in this Meta.SE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/303761/162102) that if there haven't been a lot more migrations, we shouldn't be looking for a custom path.  He writes:

> - Look at the last 90 days of mod-only manual migrations. If there are less than 10 - 15 of them, stop - the problem isn't big enough to warrant a migration path.
> - If more than 10 - 15 questions have been lobbed over, have more than 80% of them been well-received? If so, just ask for the migration path on either meta site. We'll dig into the database as we research it.
> - If you're seeing 80% or fewer of them being well-received, it's probably not a good idea to set up the path.